# MySQL -> SQL Server Migration Assistant with LARGE table issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, database-migration

I am trying to migrate my company's old MySQL database onto SQL Server 2008.

I'm using the SQL Server Migration assistant for MySQL software and everything works great except for the large tables (some containing about 150 million + rows) - It creates the schema, etc and when I select to migrate the data I get it staying stuck at `Migrating myTable > myTable with 0 of 159216578 rows processed` - It stays that way for about 1-2 hours then crashes and says it couldn't create an error file.

Are there any things / settings I can change to make this work?
Is there a better way (I have access to the `.frm`, `.MYD`, `.MYI` files if there's something I can do that way too) - I'm open to anything so long as I get these tables migrated.

Thanks!!

Comment: What version of SSMA are you using?  How is the network arranged between MySQL, SQL Server, and where you are running SSMA?  I just did a migration this week with a MySQL table having 5.1 million rows and it worked great.

Comment: Are you using the default settings, i.e., batch size = 1000?  I can't find any references that there should be a limit on the table size, but it seems your computer is trying to download too much data during migration (hence being stuck at `0` and then crashing).  How much RAM does the machine have that you are running SSMA on?  How much data is in a single row of this table, i.e., are there a lot of wide or binary columns, or is the schema relatively light and simple?

Comment: The MySQL data is on my local machine - `localhost` - and the SQL Server is on a remote server. As for the default settings, I am and the batch size is 1000 - any thoughts?? As ofr the 5 million-row tables, they work fine... It's the 100 million row tables that seem to be causing the issue...

Comment: ... It's a fairly complex table and these machines are 32-bit, so i'm limited to 3 gb RAM

Comment: If SSMA has already generated the schema, you can try copying the data directly from SQL Server using `OpenQuery` over an ODBC connection directly to MySQL, like this: http://blog.jamesrossiter.co.uk/2011/03/07/migrating-data-from-mysql-to-microsoft-sql-server-and-away-from-mysql-slowness/.  The challenge is you will have to handle any data translation issues yourself from MySQL to SQL Server.  I suppose you could try splitting the source table into `20` 5-million row tables.  Does your table have a natural partition key?  How big is the table on the disk?

Comment: ... I'm wondering if the ODBC connetcion has a table size limit too, but I like the idea!! As for splitting up the table, I'm hoping there's a cleaner solution, but I might have to go that way - Which might be ok since there is a primary key on the table anyways. Otherwise the table is 10 gb and the largest one I have is 40 gb <gulp>

Comment: One possibility with the `OpenQuery` is that you could technically include `WHERE` to limit how many rows come across.  So something like `INSERT SQLServerdatabasename.dbo.tablename SELECT * FROM openquery(MYSQL, ‘SELECT * FROM databasename.tablename WHERE PK BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000’)` to grab the first 1,000,000 id values, for instance.  Then just update the min/max values and run until you get all the way through the table (or use a `FOR` loop to all the # of millions needed).

Comment: ... Though I would strongly suggest testing with a small set, like 100 rows, and checking if everything is in order.  For instance, the PK values will not come over directly unless you `set identity [TableName] off`.  And you may find translation problems in some columns you'll have to deal with.

Comment: @mellamokb - Thank you SO much!! - I like that idea the most from anything else i've seen online! I'm going to try that now because I'm pretty much ready to give up otherwise :)

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise, please feel free to post your comments as a solution - you definitely deserve the credit for answering this for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to export about 10 milion rows at a time (depending on the MySQL hardware) using something in the WHERE clause that will allow you to separate the data (ID, date, etc).

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID BETWEEN x and y INTO OUTFILE 'C:\temp\data.csv';
```

You can use SQL Server Import/Export Wizard to get it into MSSQL.